# looser exception specification on overriding virtual function

Tags: c++, exception, overriding

I have a template Matrix class:

```
template <typename T, int row, int col>
class Matrix{};
```

Inside the class decleration I wrote an execption class, based on std::exception:

```
class MatrixException: public std::exception
{
private:
    const char* errmsg;
public:
    MatrixException(const char* msg="")
        :errmsg(msg) {} 
    const char* what() const {return errmsg;}
};

class IllegalOperation: public MatrixException
{
    public:
        IllegalOperation(const char* msg="")
            : MatrixException(msg) {}
};
```

I tried to use it on one of the class' functions, int the implantation part, like this:

```
template <typename T, int row, int col>
Matrix<T, row, col>& Matrix<T, row, col>::operator=(const Matrix& mat)
{
    if (condition)
        {throw IllegalOperation("Matrices sizes don't match");}
    // other stuff
    return *this;
}
```

and I get this error message:
`looser exception specification on overriding virtual function 'const char* Matrix<T, row, col>::MatrixException::what() const [with T = int; int row = 3; int col = 3]'|`

What did I do wrong?

ADDITION: I've tried one of the linked below, and it helped me. Though I did try to find a similar question myself.
I've changed the line

`const char* what() const {return errmsg;}`
to

`const char *what() const noexcept {return errmsg;}`
and it was ok.
Thanks whoever put the links!

Comment: [`what()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) should be also marked `noexcept`.

Comment: `override` would be fine.

Comment: Let's face it, you're in trouble if `what()` throws

Comment: @Yksisarvinen indeed, this was my correction. thanks!

Comment: @PaulSanders , why is that?

Comment: Because if your exception handler throws unexpectedly, what then?

Comment: @PaulSanders I have a try-catch in my main. It's a part of hw assignment, the function SHOULD fail and write a message on the screen.

Comment: OK, but if it's calling `what()`, and `what()` throws, then you'll never see that message.  That's why `what()` needs to be `noexcept` (and shouldn't throw!).